# How can continuos fractions be used in the units of siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

How can I use siunitx to create (for example):

[image]

or even a double fraction? As soon as I add / to the lower section the entire form changes to Wh/m³/h.

Is a form Wh/(m³/h) possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: That's not really one unit: it's an equation of two ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually construct the fraction:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\frac{\watt\hour}{\cubic\meter\per\hour}} 

\end{document}
```

[image]